# How to display a parent container on the main Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to display a container component and using the older version of react router I have seen people do this:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router component={App}>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
  </Router>
);
```

Where my App component looks like:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <p>Hello...</p>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My package.json has this currently:

```
dependencies": {
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dnd": "^2.5.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
```

BTW, do I need to import react-router and react-router-dom and react-router-redux when using react-router 4.2?

Comment: Are you trying to render components based on routes inside your App component ?

Comment: I don't think you can use Router like that, at least not in react-router v4. What you could do is use <Route component={App}> which is just using a Route instead. And then you wrap a Router around all that. You don't need to import react-router if you've already import react-router-dom, and you don't need to import redux if you're not using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just write it like that:

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <App />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: I got an error: ```A <Router> may have only one child element ```

Answer (score 0):

> Please degrade react-router to 2.3.0.

Hope it will work.